# How could I recognize private pages and public pages from QuerySets of Wagtail page?

Tags: django, private, wagtail, public

when I make a API from wagtail, I have get QuerySets(contain private pages and public pages), then how could i recognize the private pages and public pages? the database tables don't have on filed to recognize it. I know how to get private QuerySets and public QuerySets, use case like below:

Page.objects.filter().all().public().live()
Page.objects.filter().all().not_public().live()

is there any filed i can use,like page.private to get this attribute?

Comment: please add your model that can say what can you do

Comment: Thanks for your asking, I had solved this problem via @gasman provided method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page model has a `get_view_restrictions()` method, which returns a queryset of restrictions that apply to the page; if this is empty, the page is public.

```
is_private = page.get_view_restrictions().exists()
```

Comment: Thank you,it's really help me to get the right result.Thanks again.